# Problem generating Geodatabase Diagrammer

Tags: arcgis-10.1, diagram

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and Visio 2010.  When I am trying to generate the diagram using the geodatabase diagrammer it has the following to error messages:

Source at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.DocumentsClass.Add(StringFileName) at GeodatabaseDiagrammer.VisioDiagram.OpenVisioDrawing(String fileName, String pathName) in C:\agis\Tools\ArcGIS\10x\GeodatabaseDiagrammer\AddInSourceCode\Version1.2\GeodatabaseDiagrammer\Helpers\VisioDiagram.vb:line 102

Msg: File not found.

Then it would pop up another dialog box and say
Source: at GeodatabaseDiagrammer.VisioDiagram.SectionHeader() in C:\agis\Tools\ArcGIS\10x\GeodatabaseDiagrammer\AddInSourceCode\Version1.2\GeodatabaseDiagrammer\Helpers\VisoDiagram.vb:line 160

Msg: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: was this version of Geodatabase Diagrammer downloaded from http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5af1723bab4e413bae63dd89daa87984 ??

Comment: no, it is from http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a378b48be11b45b5bb25254643304cb7

Comment: do you have 32bit or 64 bit versions of Visio (2010,2012?)?

Comment: I have 32 bits Visio.  But I am running it on 64 bits Window 7.

Answer (score 3):

When I set this up, I had to update the templates to Visio 2010, then specify the default location for them in Visio.  And if I recall correctly, I had to have visio already open the first time I ran it.
To update the templates, just open them, and save them again as template.  You may have to do the same for the Stencils.  The templates and stencils should be in the install package.

To load the templates:
1) Start Visio
2) Click on Options (small button below HELP)
3) Click Advanced, then scroll down to File Locations
4) under Templates, browse to the folder containing the templates (there is on for True Type Fonts TTF, and one for Post Script PS).
5) repeat step 4 for the Stencils.

Once this is done, leave Visio open, and try generating the diagram from ArcCatalog.

Good luck

Comment: I had to do this and also add both versions of Program files and my network paths to trusted locations(inc sub folders) in Visio

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and finally traced it down in my case to the fact that both the GeodatabaseDiagrammerTT.vst and GeodatabaseDiagrammerPS.vst Visio template files that were provided in the installation files were corrupted. You can verify this on your version of Visio (mine is 2007 Standard) by double-clicking on the .vst’s and seeing if they open in Visio. To solve the problem, I renamed the EGeodatabaseDiagrammerTT.vst file to GeodatabaseDiagrammerTT.vst and all was well. I also replaced the GeodatabaseDiagrammerTT.vss stencil file with the EGeodatabaseDiagrammerTT.vss version, but that didn’t have any discernible effect one way or another. Since I don’t use the Postscript option for font generation, I didn’t attempt to set up a new GeodatabaseDiagrammerPS.vst template file. Hope this solution works for some folks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by making sure I did not have Visio open when I ran the tool.